# I want some critique on my writing

Tags: fiction, style, novel, criticism

Laying in a pool of vomit at one o clock on a tuesday morning in the room of a lousy hotel room was not a situation peter ever thought hed find himself in. But as fate would have it he lay there lifeless as roadkill on the damp carpented floor of the sleazy hotel that reeked of alcohol and cheap cigareets.

Comment: Welcome, but I'm afraid this site doesn't offer critique. I'm sorry. Perhaps you should read the Tour page to see what we _do_ offer. @y.singh

Comment: But I'd suggest that if you request critique, make sure that your spelling is correct first.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not like other sites. We are not a discussion board or an online workshop. We require clear, answerable questions which have the potential to help others. While we do handle some critique questions if they fall within a narrow set of guidelines, as written this does not fit. Please take our tour and see our help center writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what kinds of questions the community answers here.

Comment: This is all scene setting, which I find is better as the character is doing something. Get the character off the floor, walking around, doing things. I suspect this section will be deleted in your further revisions.

Answer (score 1):

Critiques are off topic here. But I think something may be learned here.

The first sentence is too long. When I come to "in the room of ...", I feel that I want the sentence to wrap up and not extend itself futher. Reading on, "the lousy hotel room" is repeated in "the sleazy hotel". So there are two reasons to cut that from the first sentence. "Laying" is repeated also, so find a different verb here or in the first sentence. Also, your spelling is wrong (shoud be "lying", "he'd", "o'clock", "Tuesday"). Finally, is the floor damp or does the hotel reek of alcohol and cigarettes? Both, but both is too much for one sentence. So turn the smell into a new sentence, if possible not a purely descriptive one, but one that drives on the action. (And what is a "carpented floor"? Did you mean a carpet or parquet?) Oh, and a "pool of vomit" is not damp. It seems to me you are not actually describing a scene, but simply throwing together stereotypic phrases that do not properly fit. First, come up with a clear mental image, then describe it, and do not get carried away by the sound of the words.

Maybe:

> Passing out in a pool of vomit at one o'clock on a Tuesday morning was not a situation Peter ever thought he'd find himself in. But as fate would have it, there he lay, on the floor of a sleazy hotel room, lifeless as roadkill and unperturbed by the stink of cigarettes and alcohol that the old man breathed into his nose, thinking him dead and trying to bring him back to life.